# How to set up AMF PHP 2.2 using composer

Tags: php, amfphp

I've installed AMF PHP 2.2 via composer so source resides on vendor directory and my vendor directory not inside the web root. How do i bypass or route to amf back office and service directory which placed on the web root?

Comment: For the gateway, see http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/best-practices-for-long-term-projects/ for creating a redirection. For the backoffice you might have some luck playing with .htaccess, but the simplest is to move the BackOffice folder to your webroot. This is something that needs to be addressed in a future release.

Comment: yeah. you are right ,I was doing so with my earlier projects by moving  the entire backoffice to the web root.

Answer (score 0):

Using Amfphp installed via Composer in a Laravel controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Amfphp_Core_HttpRequestGatewayFactory;
use Amfphp_Core_Config;

class AmfphpController extends Controller {

    public function amfphp() {

        $myConfig = new Amfphp_Core_Config();
        $myConfig->serviceFolders = array();
        $myConfig->serviceFolders [] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Services/';

        $gateway = Amfphp_Core_HttpRequestGatewayFactory::createGateway($myConfig);

        $gateway->service();
        $gateway->output();

    }
}
```

Put your services in app/Http/Services directory